# How to make a full local backup of my phone

Tags: backup, android-12

I'm trying to find a way to have a full backup of my phone (apps, settings, data, life universe and everything...) but from what I read on the internet tools such as Titanium and Helium backup are not working anymore on new phones (mine is running on Android 12) so I didn't even bother, also I can't use methods that require rooting since that will void my warranty and the phone is only few months old.

I tried running this command:

```
adb backup -apk -obb -shared -all -system -f fullbackup.ab
```

But after a while it stops (at around 17-19 GB, always a different number), creating an incomplete backup. The first time after a backup I tried extracting it but the process exited saying it was an incomplete archive.

I read that this might be cause by active apps, I tried closing them but it didn't help (guess it's some system app), I also found that sometimes it might be caused by not setting a backup password, but that didn't work either

So I would like to know if there's either a better way to fully backup my phone in 2023, or how to make `adb backup` work.

Thanks

Comment: Possible dupe: [How to fully backup non-rooted devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/44325). While the answers may be old, AFAIK it's impossible to do a full local backup using only ADB, moreover because each app can opt-out from being backed up.

Comment: As far as I know `adb backup` does no longer work on recent apps on Android 12: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/231237/2241

Comment: I'm more concerned about data and settings, I guess apps can be recovered from google drive backup? (I don't have enough space to do a full backup on gdrive)

Comment: Still, my issue with adb backup is that it starts but then it stops after a while without completing the backup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fully backup non-rooted devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/how-to-fully-backup-non-rooted-devices)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no method to make a full backup of android smartphones. It is always only a partial backup, be it `adb backup` or google drive.

I recommend to manually backup your files from ADB:

```
adb pull -a /sdcard
```

You can backup apps with Google as explained [here](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1036182).  Also Swift Backup or Google One can backup app data of some apps.

For `adb backup` it's important to know [only apps that allow it in `AndroidManifest.xml` can be backed up with ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/231235).

You can split backup into packages.  Only backup apps that you know. you can try [`list_app_labels.sh`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/250521) or list packages from [cmd line](https://adbshell.com/commands/adb-shell-pm-list-packages):

```
adb shell pm list packages -3
adb shell pm list packages -s
```

for example

```
adb backup -f chrome.ab -apk com.android.chrome
```

AFAIK Helium can do this, but you can also try [another automated script for splitting backup into packages](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar).

**Beware:** even in case app data is backed up for single packages, it's not guaranteed it will restore on other devices.

Comment: Thanks It looks like it worked! I had to use a different command than adb pull because it would file on a file it couldn't read. I found this instead https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226573/adb-pull-stops-after-first-error I saw your post on xda too, thanks!