# Data protection (making files persist across time)

Tags: security, google-account, google

In this post I am addressing a real issue that Android users may face.

Suppose, over the course of my lifetime, I have been storing my files in Google Drive. These, may be important files. Perhaps I have taken years to put them together, and put them together well.

Storing my files, as a backup place, in Google drive, has allowed me to keep my stuff in one place, through college, as I moved apartments, as I went to hospital, and as I moved households.

Alas, the files were not safe. For example, changing partners, is a tough one for your files.

For example, your partner may go into a fit and take your Android device, use the shared accounts feature, log into your Google drive, and delete your files.

Perhaps you were sick at one time, and needed to share your password with your partner. You may even develop some mind disabling condition, your partner may become your carer, and your files will not be safe because your partner may do whatever they want with your files, including deleting them, while you are too disabled to access them manage them and go through them.

Or, perhaps, you moved households. Your new partner is your only resort. Perhaps your parents won't keep you at home, and you need someone to live with, you cannot handle being alone.

But your partner won't talk to you or get into conversations.

One day, they log in to Google Drive, and, decide there is not enough space for Google Pictures, and, without even understanding anything about space or file sizes, and, without even asking you, deletes all your important files from Google Drive.

Perhaps, at your former home you bought a safe, with a hardware lock, to place copied USB keys into it, so that you may not lose your files and others may not take it. Perhaps you have placed the safe key into a hardware device with a programmable numeric lock, so that you do not lose it.

Perhaps, your home is not a home.

It is just a place where people do whatever they want with your stuff. They break hardware devices at times, so that your always have to buy cheap ones (and always make sure you store your data in a safe remote place so that when your hardware breaks you do not lose everything).

Perhaps, you need one apartment for yourself, and one for living with the rest of the family, but that is not affordable.

Well, all of this may seem of topic. But these are real social problems, and it would be nice if Google and Android somehow solved them.

I have asked on the Information Security stack exchange, but they don't seem to care less that my files could go lost.

The question is, can I store my files in the Google cloud from Android, so, that they cannot be deleted (not even from my Android device)? Why doesn't anyone provide such a service?

A service that would require phone verification to delete your files in the cloud, with voice recognition, or fingerprint access, and, even then, the files are moved, but not deleted.

A service where you pay for storage of files that once stored cannot be deleted, where storing a file in the cloud requires voice or fingerprint access, because, you have to prevent someone from uploading files that will take up too much of your file quota as a malicious action.

Please don't delete my post, or migrate it to the psychology stack exchange. I need a solution really badly. This would be really important.

It would be nice for people to have more support with regards to file handling and household file handling and safety.

Please don't just delete my post and leave me with no support. Give me a solution. I cannot change household just to protect my data.

Thanks.

Thank you for being a good fellow programmer and sharing or providing solutions to deal with these use cases.

Why do I care so much about my files? Because it's my work. It's my lifetime. It's my time. It's my intellectual investment. What have I been working for if I must lose everything?

Perhaps I am even concerned that my children may one day find themselves in the same situation.

Why doesn't anyone implement a solution?

Comment: If you care about your data that much, you should keep multiple backups. And the best form of backup (from multiple aspects) is a local drive, not the remote backup services. Keep at least 2 portable SSDs and backup your data to them on daily, weekly, or monthly basis, depending on how much data loss you can afford at maximum. Want to avoid the hassle of connecting drives? Run a small server like Raspberry Pi (which you can also use as a home router and) which you can connect to from your mobile phones and PCs for backup purpose even on hourly basis. Or you can get a server in cloud computing.

Comment: Why doesn't anyone read what I wrote. I need a storage solution that backs up, does not store files at home but remotely, and does not allow file deletion.

Comment: 1) We are not Google, we don't control the access policies for Google accounts. Anyone authorized by you via Google data access rights to delete/modify files/data can do so. 2) Be aware of [Does adb backup/restore still work because it says it's deprecated?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/231235/3573) which means that for those apps without cloud backup/exporting data support,  app data may be lost. 3) Please look at [How to automate regular Google Takeout backups to cloud storage](https://superuser.com/q/716756/149731) if you still wish to use Google services.

Comment: I found the following site [iDrive Google Workspace Backups](https://www.idrive.com/google-workspace-backup/). However, I'm not sure whether I understand whether that takes care of my problem.

Comment: Because you can automate a Google Takeout, but you still have the problem of figuring out a place where to put it where nobody deletes it or gets rid of it.

Comment: Hi. iDrive does not solve my problem because you can still accidentally delete backups on the servers it someone can log into your account and delete them. No solution yet.

Comment: Perhaps what I need is an [immutable backup service](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.veeam.com/blog/immutable-backup.html%3famp=1).

Comment: Unfortunately veeam only services companies, not individuals searching for an immutable backup solution.