# Downloading everything from Google Drive and putting everything in a USB key

Tags: google, google-drive, google-keep

This post is related to [my former post on internet security and Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/254269/data-protection-making-files-persist-across-time).

I want to download my entire Google Drive and put it on a USB key.

The USB key will not be safe. It can be lost. It can be formatted and overwritten.

However, I could store it in a safe in a bank, if I had the money.

Alternatively, I could just take my chances.

However, I am afraid Google Drive won't let me do this, because doing so would just take up too much bandwidth.

Other apps such as Google Keep may not even provide the support to do this (a backup from which notes could be restored).

Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for, without having to download one file at a time.

Thanks.

Is this a use case that Google has been taking into account to catering to.

I don't think that Google, a big giant concerned with user friendless and customer support, would be concerned about losing customers by catering towards bulk data downloading.

If anything, users would appreciate it.

Some users could be concerned about someone logging in and downloading all of their data at once.

If this is the case, they could make the bulk download accessible though phone voice verification or fingerprint verification on a separate date section, is it not so?

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to download everything from Google Drive, then I believe [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout) should help.

Comment: You forgot one way of losing data stored on an USB stick: as USB sticks typically contain the cheapest available flash memory chips available on the market a lot of them simply go defect after some time. So keep I mind that USB st.icks is the most unreliable way to store data. Also keep in mind that flash memory is not a good long term storage. Flash memory should at least be powered on one a year so it can detect corruption and try to fix it before it reaches a critical level.