Complete android backup
I want to make the most complete backup of absolutely the entire phone. As I understand it, there are no simple ways. But is it true that I can simply copy all the files from the root via the computer + make a backup of applications via adb? Do I understand correctly that in this way I will not lose anything except the data of some applications created automatically? Or maybe it’s possible to somehow copy the entire file system of the phone, so that later you can download it again to the phone, or extract data from this backup?

If you have read about adb backup then it will only run on old devices (backup and restore) please read https://android.stackexchange.com/q/231235/2241. And copying all data is only possible on a (already) rooted phone and even there you will loose all data that is encrypted using the hardware KeyStore AndroidKeystore.

If you mean backing up partitions, you can back up an Android device using mtkclient installed on Windows or Linux, and disassemble the backup using WWR. I'd be happy to expand if that's what you mean.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I'm interested, if you have to to write up an explanation.  Thanks!

Answers need to be self supporting without having to go elsewhere.  Please expand.
